# Division by zero in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run a script wherein division by zero should result in error. Upon running the script, found out that inputbox for x divided by 0 is accepted by the system and resulting in run time error which pointing to line:

```
    calculator = x / x1
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you intended this code to protect you from the "division by 0" error:

```
ElseIf num2 = x Then
msgbox "Error, cannot divide any number to 0"
```

But this code never gets executed, because earlier you have the code `If IsNumeric(num2) Then Exit do` which exits the Do loop when the user enters 0.

Furthermore, you have to execute that code only for the "DIVIDE" operation.

I.e., your code should contain something like this before calling `calculator`:

```
If num2 = 0 And (LCase(operation) = "divide") Then
    msgbox "Division by zero!"
    WScript.Quit
End If
```